# bref_daily_pitcher() function from baseballr package stops working after first use

Tags: r, package

I am using the function bref_daily_pitcher() from the baseballr package to get daily pitching data from the Internet for the 2022 season. My code is likely bad, but is as follows:

```
library(baseballr)
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2022/04/07"), as.Date("2022/10/05"), by = "day")
datapitcher <- bref_daily_pitcher(dates[1], dates[1])
datapitcher$Date <- dates[1]

for (i in 2:length(dates)) {
  temporary <- bref_daily_pitcher(dates[i], dates[i])
  temporary$Date <- dates[i]
  datapitcher <- rbind(datapitcher, temporary)
}

write.csv(datapitcher, "pitcherdata.csv")
```

In past instances, my code worked and produced the desired result. However, after running it once today, it has stopped working. When I run the following line:

```
datapitcher <- bref_daily_pitcher(dates[1], dates[1])
```

I get the message:

```
2023-04-12 10:26:27: Invalid arguments or no daily pitcher data available!
```

Which is decidedly false and datapitcher becomes stored as a function in the environment as the following:

```
function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) 
{
  if (missing(ncp)) 
    .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)
  else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)
}
```

Can someone help me understand what's going on? Also the code works on someone else's computer (not sure if it would work a few times though).

Comment: It seems the url schema for baseball-reference.com has changed a bit, and furthermore it looks like they have improved bot detection. When I update the url I do get results when pasted in a browser window, but the R code returns HTTP error 429 which is a rate limited request error. The first issue (new url schema) can be addressed by the author of `baseballr` but the second issue cannot.